# Synchronizing Inter-process access for Updating a common file

Tags: python, concurrency, python-3.6

I have two scripts that are updating the same file. Both can run at the same time. How can I prevent inconsistent updates to the file? In other words, how to serialize access to the file?

Let me explain the question. Suppose there is a shelf file and 2 scripts are updating it. Script 1 does this:

```
import shelve
sf = shelve.open('some_file')
sf[key1] = data1
sf.close()
```

Script 2 has the following code:

```
import shelve
sf = shelve.open('some_file')
sf[key2] = data2
sf.close()
```

Suppose script 2 is scheduled after script 1 opens the file. When script 2 completes and control returns to script 1, script 1 will do its update and close the file. This will result in script 2's update getting lost. How to prevent this from happening so that both updates are made to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a coarse lock to ensure that only a single client is allowed to access the file at any given time.

since you're in separate processes you need some sort of shared resource that can be read from all collaborators.

Redis provides a couple primitives that make this easier (TTL on locks), and since it is single threaded helps to reason about concurrent access to it:

https://redis.io/topics/distlock

Comment: Can it be done using the Standard Library? Can I use the lock feature in the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: `redlock` doesn't explicitly lock the file. It creates a lock on a string which represents the resource (file). But it does the job.